# Effect of the position of a callback in an asynchronous function

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to understand asynchronous callbacks in NodeJS by following [this guide](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) and i have a question about the position of `callback()` in the code snippet below.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var myNumber = undefined

function addOne(callback) {
  fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
    myNumber++
    callback()
  })
}

function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(myNumber)
}

addOne(logMyNumber)
```

Here, my file `'number.txt'` contains the number 1 and the output of this entire code snippet is `2`. This appears to be invoking `callback()` after the file is read, and the output is expected. However, moving `callback()` outside of `fs.readFile()` but inside `addOne()` as shown below has confused me as the output is now `undefined`.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var myNumber = undefined

function addOne(callback) {
  fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
    myNumber++
  })
  callback()
}

function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(myNumber)
}

addOne(logMyNumber)
```

Does this mean that in the second example, `callback()` is invoked before `fs.readFile()` has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is right. Node.js executes `fs.readFile` but **DOES NOT** wait for it's completion.

So the execution moves to next statement, which invokes the callback and the result is `undefined` because the previous command has not yet finished.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous programming is very interesting, but easy thing.
Asynchronous executions means that program won't run your code synchronously line by line waiting for completing each line of code **WHEN YOU ARE EXECUTING BLOCKING CODE**, but instead it will do concurrent execution (concurrency).

Blocking code is when you are doing for example http requests, reading files as in your example or DOM events in browser. Basically blocking code is code which is not depended on your code. Basically blocking code is when your program should wait unknown duration till their completion to continue.

On basic javascript operations like arithmetic and array operations, loops e.g.
Code runs synchronously because they are not depended on external resources.

That is why we have callbacks in JavaScript to not wait for their completion.
Callbacks helps us to run code after asynchronous code executed. 
Asynchronous means that our code is **NON-BLOCKING**.

So in your code when you run

```
fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
    myNumber++
})
callback()
```

It will start running `fs.readFile` and immediately will start execution of `callback` function.

But when when you run

```
fs.readFile('number.txt', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    myNumber = parseInt(fileContents)
    myNumber++
    callback()
})
```

It will start executing `fs.readFile` and within his **callback** `doneReading` function will do operations with `myNumber` and will execute `callback`

Most of JavaScript asynchronous functions have callback functions.

You can read about blocking and non-blocking codes [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/), also here about [callbacks](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-callbacks-explained-using-minions-da272f4d9bcd)

Also you can read about `promises` and `async/await`.
They are very cool things, that helps you to struct your code as you would in synchronous environment, but runs asynchronous code.